# Case study for managing revenue in hospitals using journey mapping

Tags: ux-designer, user-journey, case-studies, journey-map

I am looking for UX case studies that resolved revenue management systems in hardware service deliveries in hospitals & clinics.

Comment: I believe this question is not suitable for this site. This isn't a place where you can ask people to do your searching for you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually I did plenty of research which possibly I could. That's why I raised my hand for help.

Comment: Well that may be true, but it still doesn't make your question valid for this site. The SE network has strict rules on what questions are on/off topic and your question is likely to be closed. Please refer to [help] for advice on how to ask a valid question here

Comment: Okay. I will refer to the guidelines. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try reframing the question in terms of the design problems/issues/challenges that you are aiming to solve by finding examples of case studies, and you might get closer to the answer/opinions that you need from the community. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We have published one case study on [revenue management system in hospitals](https://www.koruux.com/case-studies/medapparatus/). Hope it help you to resolving your queries.

Comment: Hey,
maybe you can summarize the core findings so they are still accessible even when the links goes dead.